# Hangfire dashboard with Servicestack self host

Tags: servicestack, owin, hangfire

I'm using ServiceStack for self host (AppSelfHostBase), and I need to use hangfire dashboard. I do add Owin Startup class in the project but when I run it, nothing is displayed.

```
 private static Logger Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
        private AppHost _serviceStackHost;
        private HostControl _hostControl;

        public JobWinService()
        {
            //Nothing should be added here
            _serviceStackHost = null;
            _hostControl = null;
        }

        bool ServiceControl.Start(HostControl hostControl)
        {
            _hostControl = hostControl;
            Logger.Info("--------> U-Bet Job Service starting <--------");
            try
            {
                if (_serviceStackHost == null)
                {
                    var listeningOn = "http://*:" + Properties.Settings.Default.ServicePort + "/";
                    _serviceStackHost = new AppHost();
                    _serviceStackHost.Init();
                    _serviceStackHost.Start(listeningOn);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Warn(ex, "Exception occured:{0}", ex.Message);
                return false;
            }
            Logger.Info("--------> U-Bet Job Service started <--------");
            return true;
        }
```